# Can a SharePoint WebPart connect to a custom SharePoint WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to consume a value passed by the default sharepoint filter webpart. I don't see how a custom sharepoint webpart can establish a connect and get data. Is this even possible?

**Updated**

**The provider WebPart is a default SharePoint List Filter WebPart.
The consumer WebPart is a custom WebPart**

This is the code I came up with, but the "connections" option is still greyed out on the SharePoint page. On the page, I have a SharePoint List Filter WebPart and my CustomPageViewer WebPart.

```
namespace PageViewerWithConnections.CustomPageViewer
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class CustomPageViewer : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
    {
        IFilterValues _filterVals;

        [ConnectionConsumer("Consumer connection", "Consumer param")]
        public void ConsumeFilter(IFilterValues filterValues)
        {
            _filterVals = filterValues;
        }

        Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.PageViewerWebPart objPageViewer;
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Reason's for this approach**
My goal is to set a different URL to the page viewer Web Part based on the value I get from a SharePoint List Filter Web Part. It seems that the SharePoint List Filter WebPart cannot send data to a Page Viewer WebPart.

Comment: Is the consumer WebPart a SharePoint 2010 "Visual WebPart"?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create a consumer method on your custom webpart that takes an instance of `IFilterValues` as an argument and uses the `ConnectionConsumerAttribute` Attribute.

```
private IFilterValues _filterVals;

[ConnectionConsumer("Filter Consumer", "FilterConsumer")]
public void ConsumeFilter(IFilterValues filterValues)
{
    _filterVals = filterValues;
}
```

*Note that the consumption of the filter values occurs during the `OnPreRender` stage of the page lifecycle, so you'll need to override the `OnRender` method to act on any values consumed from the connection, or include the logic in the consumer method.*

For more information, check out these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms494838(v=office.12).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765.aspx

Comment: Hi Kyle, I updated the question with some code but the "connections" property on the WebPart is still greyed out.

Comment: Which list filter web part are you using?  Is this an out of the box web part, or something that you installed?

Comment: I believe it is the out of the box web part.

Answer (score 1):

In the CreateChildControls you should call base.CreateChildControls();

Here is some working code:

```
    List<IFilterValues> providers = new List<IFilterValues>();
```

protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        if (providers.Count > 0 && providers[0].ParameterValues != null)
        {
            this.FilterValue1 = providers[0].ParameterValues[0];
        }

        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    [ConnectionConsumer("Provider WebPart", "IFilterValues", AllowsMultipleConnections = false)]
    public void SetConnectionInterface(IFilterValues provider) 
    {
        if (provider != null)
        {
            this.providers.Add(provider);
            List<ConsumerParameter> parameters = new List<ConsumerParameter>();

            parameters.Add(new ConsumerParameter("param1",
                  ConsumerParameterCapabilities.SupportsSingleValue | ConsumerParameterCapabilities.SupportsEmptyValue | ConsumerParameterCapabilities.SupportsAllValue));

           provider.SetConsumerParameters(new ReadOnlyCollection<ConsumerParameter>(parameters)); 
        } 
    }